# mysql order by clause outside select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran the following query by accident and it works, and now im' confused as to why it works. Can someone please explain how to interpret this query...

```
(select name from employe_info limit 100) order by name;
```

I always assumed the 'order by' has to be associate with an explicit select clause, but in this case it's outside the () and it works.  This is probably not a good form, but i just want to know if this works by accident or is this expected?

Thanks!

Comment: Amusing.  This looks like a `union` query without the `union`.  I guess MySQL understands this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You just apply sorting to subquery
See more in manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

> If ORDER BY occurs within a subquery and also is applied in the outer
>   query, the outermost ORDER BY takes precedence. For example, results
>   for the following statement are sorted in descending order, not
>   ascending order:
>
> (SELECT ... ORDER BY a) ORDER BY a DESC;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is only a partial query.

From [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT

and a paragraph later:

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.